# Why OpenCart uses Subquery instead of LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, opencart, opencart-3

Recently I was researching opencart source code I found that are using subqueries instead of LEFT JOIN.

Opencart v3
look it on file admin/model/user/user.php

```
$query = "SELECT *, (
        SELECT ug.name 
        FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "user_group` ug 
        WHERE ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id
    ) AS user_group
    FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "user` u
    WHERE u.user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'";
```

I would use like this

```
$query = "SELECT u.*, ug.name AS user_group 
    FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "user` u 
    LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "user_group` ug ON ug.user_group_id = u.user_group_id
    WHERE u.user_id = '" . (int)$user_id . "'";
```

My question is, Is there any performance improvement using subquery in Select column? If yes how so? If no then why this major community is using this way?
Also I found that they are not using foreign keys, any idea why?

Comment: "Scalar subqieries" enforce a cardinality equal to 1. A left join could potentially produce higher (read wrong) cardinality that you won't be aware of.

Comment: I'm scared of your English. Let me research and I'll get back to you

Comment: If the subquery returns no more than one row, there is probably no significant difference. They also don't use prepared statements. I guess the code is just very old.

Comment: @TheImpaler "A left join could potentially produce higher (read wrong) cardinality that you won't be aware of." what does that mean?

Comment: @TheImpaler what is read wrong cardinality? and how does it will be higher? I have never heard of that. Both queries are fetching from same table then how could be a "read wrong" result?

Comment: "read wrong" = "read it ('higher') as: 'wrong'".

Comment: @FaizanRupani The left join can produce multiple rows instead of a single one for each row of the main table. For example, if your `user` table had 10 rows, and the related table `user_group` had two rows per `user`, then the left join would end up producing 20 rows (wrong result) -- not 10 rows as you may have expected. The subquery -- on the other hand -- would have crashed right away, letting you know something is wrong.

Comment: @FaizanRupani Why scared of my English? Genuinely curious. Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: @TheImpaler Your vocabulary is very advanced as a programmer. It's very hard to understand and learn because I'm not native English speaking person. You need to simplify it for junior programmer like me to understand it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correlated subquery can become a performance problem when the outer query is processing a bloatload of rows; because the subquery gets executed for each row.

It looks like this query returns at most one row, because it looks like `user_id` is a unique key. Since the outer query returns (at most) a single row, the subquery will get executed only one time.

It also looks like `user_group_id` is a unique key in the `user_group` table, so that subquery will return at most one row.  (In the more general case, if the subquery returns more that one row, we'd get an error. With the LEFT JOIN, we'd get multiple rows returned.)

---

*Q: Is there any performance improvement using subquery in Select column?*

A: There won't be a performance penalty with either form. The form with correlated subquery might be faster, but the difference is not significant.

*Q: If yes how so? If no then why this major community is using this way?*

A: It's valid SQL, it works, and there's no impetus to make a change.

*Q: Also I found that they are not using foreign keys, any idea why?*

A: There is no requirement to have the RDBMS enforce referential integrity; if the application is handling it, then we can avoid overhead in the database.

Some storage engines (e.g. MyISAM) don't enforce foreign key constraints.

And foreign keys can sometimes interfere with administrative operations, such has emptying and reloading a table.

---

It's all design decisions; there are multiple ways to skin a cat. (We're just skimming the surface here; diving deeper would be more opinion based, to make arguments for which way to skin a cat is better.)

Comment: So should I use correlated subquery with every query which give result only one row instead of left joins? Or should I stick to left joins for one row query?

Comment: In my experience, correlated subqueries generally have worse performance. There are some cases where they have better performance, but those tend to be the exception, rather than the rule. In the case of your question, the join version is probably faster.

Comment: Faizan... use whichever pattern is most appropriate. Avoid correlated subqureries that will get executed multiple times.  @Uueerdo: In my experience, a correlated subquery in the SELECT list of a query that returns a single row, so the correlated subquery is run once, with suitable index available, there is no significant difference in performance as compared to an equivalent result returned with a JOIN. When correlated subqueries get executed multiple times, that's where the performance drag comes in.

Comment: @spencer7593 agreed, correlated queries executed few times have relatively little cost, can be easier to understand, and can even be faster when the results of outer query are relatively small compared to the data being correlated.